# Read DropBox info.json file with .NetJSON

Tags: vb.net, json.net

Any ideas, I don't understand the Object I need to define. I am coding in VB but C# is OK. The file is one line but seems to have some nesting with Personal and Business.

```
{
  "personal": {
    "path": "C:\\Users\\Paul\\Dropbox (Personal)",
    "host": 4897400149,
    "is_team": false,
    "subscription_type": "Basic"
  },
  "business": {
    "path": "C:\\Users\\Paul\\Dropbox (Y2016)",
    "host": 4897401185,
    "is_team": true,
    "subscription_type": "Business"
  }
}
```

Comment: {"personal": {"path": "C:\\Users\\Paul\\Dropbox (Personal)", "host": 4897400149, "is_team": false, "subscription_type": "Basic"}, "business": {"path": "C:\\Users\\Paul\\Dropbox (YEA2016)", "host": 4897401185, "is_team": true, "subscription_type": "Business"}} is actually what is in the file. My editor was un-escaping it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your classes as follows:

```
Public Class DropBoxFolderPath
    Public Property path As String
    Public Property host As Long
    Public Property is_team As Boolean
    Public Property subscription_type As String
End Class

Public Class DropBoxFolderPaths
    Public Property personal As DropBoxFolderPath
    Public Property business As DropBoxFolderPath
End Class
```

Then deserialize as follows:

```
Dim dropBoxFolders = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DropBoxFolderPaths)(jsonString)
```

Example [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JkO2NM).  Related documentation: [How can I programmatically find the Dropbox folder paths?](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/4584).